# Undefined index cookie error in error.log file. How can I solve this?

Tags: php, cookies, undefined

I'm getting hundreds of error notifications (Undefined index:) in the **error.log** file

I check the cookies:

This is ok:

```
$d = time() + (60*60*24*365);
if (!isset($_COOKIE['pont']) || empty($_COOKIE['pont']))
   setcookie('pont','1',$d,'/');
```

The error occurs whenever you try to assign the value of the cookie to a variable, like:

```
$id1 = $_COOKIE['pont'];
```

The interesting thing is that even with the error messages in the **error.log** file, the script is *working perfectly*.

Comment: So you are able to use `if(!isset($_COOKIE['pont']))` in one place, but using the opposite of that condition in a different place eludes you …?

Comment: Not me, just the error.log file...

Answer (score 0):

`$_COOKIE` contains data about cookies that the browser sent when it requested this URL.

`setcookie` will output an HTTP response header that will cause the browser to add or update a cookie. The browser will send that cookie back in **future** requests.

`setcookie` **doesn't** populate `$_COOKIE`.

---

You probably want to approach this with something along the lines of:

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE['pont']) || empty($_COOKIE['pont'])) {
    $d = time() + (60*60*24*365);
    $new_cookie_value = '1';
    setcookie('pont',$new_cookie_value,$d,'/');
    $id1 = $new_cookie_value;
} else {
    $id1 = $_COOKIE['pont'];
}
```